# Error Installing ruby-rvm

Tags: package-management, ruby, rails, rvm

When I try to install ruby-rvm, I get this...

```
$ sudo apt-get install ruby-rvm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ruby-rvm : Depends: libreadline-gplv2-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Alright, fine, so I'll install libreadline-gplv2-dev.

```
$ sudo apt-get install libreadline-gplv2-dev 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libsdl-ttf2.0-0 libdb5.1-java-gcj libdb-je-java gcj-4.6-jre-lib libecj-java ttf-dejavu-extra eclipse-platform-data ruby1.9.1-examples gcj-4.6-base
  libxerces2-java libswt-gtk-3-jni libgcj-bc libjtidy-java gstreamer0.10-fluendo-mp3:i386 libicu4j-java libservlet2.4-java libswt-cairo-gtk-3-jni
  libcommons-beanutils-java junit libdb-java ruby1.9.1-dev libcommons-cli-java libtcltk-ruby1.9.1 libcommons-logging-java libcommons-compress-java libgcj12
  libswt-gtk-3-java libdb5.1-java libicu4j-4.4-java libswt-gnome-gtk-3-jni libyaml-0-2 icedtea-netx-common libjsch-java libruby1.9.1-dbg jarwrapper
  libxml-commons-resolver1.1-java libhal1 ri1.9.1 libapache-pom-java libxt-dev libxml-commons-external-java tzdata-java libcommons-el-java
  libservlet2.5-java libcommons-httpclient-java libslf4j-java libasm3-java libregexp-java fastjar libjasper-java libruby1.9.1 libcommons-codec-java
  libcommons-lang-java libhamcrest-java liblucene2-java liboil0.3:i386 libequinox-osgi-java libcommons-parent-java libcommons-collections3-java
  ruby1.9.1-full libgcj-common libcommons-digester-java libjetty-java libjline-java ruby1.9.1 libswt-webkit-gtk-3-jni libswt-glx-gtk-3-jni
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libreadline5
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libreadline-dev libreadline6-dev r-base-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libreadline-gplv2-dev libreadline5
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 3 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 375 kB of archives.
After this operation, 258 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

That looks bad.  This will meddle with my java installation and remove r-base-dev?  What's up with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use the package **ruby-rvm** it's outdated and contains old (and buggy) version of RVM, you can read about this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9056395/497756

I plan to release mainatained package for RVM 2.x, but in the package you try to install is out of my control and I have no possibility (and time) to fix it.

Answer (score -1):

It is better to use [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/), it follows UNIX conventions making integration with other UNIX tools easier.